# Scale out mechanism is .NET Aspire

Tags: .net, .net-8.0, dotnet-aspire

How do I scale out instances of a project in .NET Aspire horizontally?

For instance, in the following example, "products" project is being added, but how to instruct .NET Aspire that multiple instances are needed:

> builder.AddProject<Projects.Products>("products");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WithReplicas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/aspire.hosting.projectresourcebuilderextensions.withreplicas?view=dotnet-aspire-8.0)

> Configures how many replicas of the project should be created for the
> project.

Example Usage:

```cs
builder.AddProject<Projects.Products>("products").WithReplicas(2);
```

However, I would advise you to refrain from applying this to a project that applies or works on database migrations.